# How do I access template cache? - Django

Tags: python, django, caching, django-templates, django-cache

I am **caching html** within a few templates e.g.:

```
{% cache 900 stats %}
    {{ stats }}
{% endcache %}
```

Can I access the cache using the **low level** library? e.g.

```
html = cache.get('stats')
```

I really need to have some fine-grained control over the template caching :)

---

**Any ideas?** Thanks everyone! :D

Answer (score 6):

This is how I access the template cache in my project:

```
from django.utils.hashcompat import md5_constructor
from django.utils.http import urlquote

def someView(request):
    variables = [var1, var2, var3] 
    hash = md5_constructor(u':'.join([urlquote(var) for var in variables]))
    cache_key = 'template.cache.%s.%s' % ('table', hash.hexdigest())

    if cache.has_key(cache_key):
        #do some stuff...
```

The way I use the `cache` tag, I have:

```
    {% cache TIMEOUT table var1 var2 var3 %}
```

You probably just need to pass an empty list to `variables`. 
So, your`variables` and cache_`key` will look like:

```
    variables = []
    hash = md5_constructor(u':'.join([urlquote(var) for var in variables]))
    cache_key = 'template.cache.%s.%s' % ('stats', hash.hexdigest())
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code for the `cache` templatetag, the key is generated like this:

```
args = md5_constructor(u':'.join([urlquote(resolve_variable(var, context)) for var in self.vary_on]))
cache_key = 'template.cache.%s.%s' % (self.fragment_name, args.hexdigest())
```

so you could build something simliar in your view to get the cache directly: in your case, you're not using any `vary_on` parameters so you could use an empty argument to `md5_constructor`.

Comment: thanks for this, I tried `cache.get('template.cache.stat_table.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e')` but it just returns back as None

Comment: I couldn't get this to work unless I supplied [] for vary_on - putting in an empty md5_constructor gave a different base64 part of the key. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821297/django-how-to-tell-if-a-template-fragment-is-already-cached/4821681#4821681